# JPA2: Case-insensitive like matching anywhere

Tags: java, criteria, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria

I have been using Hibernate Restrictions in JPA 1.0 ( Hibernate driver ). There is defined `Restrictions.ilike("column","keyword", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)` which tests if the keyword matching the column anywhere and it is case-insensitive.

Now, I am using JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink as driver so I have to use "Restrictions" build-in JPA 2.0. I found `CriteriaBuilder` and method `like`, I have also found out how to make it matching anywhere ( although it is aweful and manual ), but still I haven't figured out how to do it case-insensitive.

There is my current aweful solution:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
EntityType<User> type = em.getMetamodel().entity(User.class);
Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);

// Where   
// important passage of code for question  
query.where(builder.or(builder.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("username", String.class)), "%" + keyword + "%"),
        builder.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("firstname", String.class)), "%" + keyword + "%"),
        builder.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("lastname", String.class)), "%" + keyword + "%")
        ));

// Order By
query.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("lastname")),
            builder.asc(root.get("firstname")));

// Execute
return em.createQuery(query).
            setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE + 1).
            setFirstResult((page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE).
            getResultList();
```

**Questions:**

Is there any function like in Hibernate driver?

Am I using the JPA 2.0 criteria correctly? This is awkward and uncomfortable solution in compare to Hibernate Restrictions.

Or can anybody help me how to change my solution to be case-insensitive, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It may seem a little awkward at first, but it is type-safe.  Building queries from strings isn't, so you notice errors at runtime instead of at compile time. You can make the queries more readable by using indentations or taking each step separately, instead of writing an entire WHERE clause in a single line.

To make your query case-insensitive, convert both your keyword and the compared field to lower case:

```
query.where(
    builder.or(
        builder.like(
            builder.lower(
                root.get(
                    type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("username", String.class)
                )
            ), "%" + keyword.toLowerCase() + "%"
        ), 
        builder.like(
            builder.lower(
                root.get(
                    type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("firstname", String.class)
                )
            ), "%" + keyword.toLowerCase() + "%"
        ), 
        builder.like(
            builder.lower(
                root.get(
                    type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("lastname", String.class)
                )
            ), "%" + keyword.toLowerCase() + "%"
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm also migrating from Hibernate to JPA and I have found JPA's API to be a little... unclear at times.  And there seems to be a lot of different ways of accomplishing the same thing - some more verbose than others.  I believe this would be a "friendlier" way of forming those like statements:    builder.like(builder.lower(root.<String>get("username")), "%"+keyword.toLowerCase()+"%")

Comment: I think it is best to use a [JPA Static Metamodel Generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html). It will ensure the properties exist at compile-time and knows the types ;-)

Comment: Watch out, comparing string lowered by the SGBD with string lowered by java may result in differences for accented character.
Example : Java : "EÉÊÈ".toLower() = "eÉÊÈ" while postgresql lower('EÉÊÈ') = 'eéêè'. I am looking fo a way to dedicate de 'lower' all to the SGBD

Comment: @Ghurdyl I just tested Java's `toLowerCase` using this code, and it succeeded. `assertThat("EÉÊÈ".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), is("eéêè"));`, and it worked, at least in version 1.8.0_144.

Comment: @RolandIllig Indeed, I wrote it the wrong way, Java toLower handles the accented characters properly, PostgreSQL (with a 'c' locale does not)
select lower('EÉÊÈ') -> eÉÊÈ. my point stays valid, comparing java toLower() with DB lower() might result in unexpected behavior. (see my answer)

Answer (score 18):

As I commented in the (currently) accepted answer, there is a pitfall using on one hand DBMS' `lower()` function and on the other hand java's `String.toLowerCase()` as both method are not warrantied to provide the same output for the same input string.

I finally found a much safer (yet not bullet-proof) solution which is to let the DBMS do all the lowering using a literal expression:

```
builder.lower(builder.literal("%" + keyword + "%")
```

So the complete solution would look like :

```
query.where(
    builder.or(
        builder.like(
            builder.lower(
                root.get(
                    type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("username", String.class)
                )
            ), builder.lower(builder.literal("%" + keyword + "%")
        ), 
        builder.like(
            builder.lower(
                root.get(
                    type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("firstname", String.class)
                )
            ), builder.lower(builder.literal("%" + keyword + "%")
        ), 
        builder.like(
            builder.lower(
                root.get(
                    type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("lastname", String.class)
                )
            ), builder.lower(builder.literal("%" + keyword + "%")
        )
    )
);
```

Edit:
As @cavpollo requested me to give example, I had to think twice about my solution and realized it's not that much safer than the accepted answer:

```
DB value* | keyword | accepted answer | my answer
------------------------------------------------
elie     | ELIE    | match           | match
Élie     | Élie    | no match        | match
Élie     | élie    | no match        | no match
élie     | Élie    | match           | no match
```

Still, I prefer my solution as it does not compare the outcome out two different functions that are supposed to work alike. I apply the very same function to all character arrays so that comparing the output become more "stable".

A bullet-proof solution would involve locale so that SQL's `lower()` become able to correctly lower accented characters. (But this goes beyond my humble knowledge)

*Db value with PostgreSQL 9.5.1 with 'C' locale

Comment: Could you add an example where the accepted answer would fail but this approach runs fine? Thanks =)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a database like Postgres which supports `ilike` which provides a much better performance as using the `lower()` function none of the provided solution solves the issue properly.

A solution can be a custom function.

The HQL query you are writing is:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE (function('caseInSensitiveMatching', name, '%test%')) = true
```

Where the `caseInSensitiveMatching` is the function name of our custom function. The `name` is the path to the property which you want to compare with and the `%test%` is the pattern which you want to match it against.

The goal is to convert the HQL query into the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE (name ilike '%test%') = true
```

To achieve this we have to implement our own dialect with our custom function registered:

```java
    public class CustomPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {
        /**
         * Default constructor.
         */
        public CustomPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
            super();
            registerFunction("caseInSensitiveMatching", new CaseInSensitiveMatchingSqlFunction());
        }

        private class CaseInSensitiveMatchingSqlFunction implements SQLFunction {

            @Override
            public boolean hasArguments() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
                return StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN;
            }

            @Override
            public String render(Type firstArgumentType, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List arguments,
                    SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {

                if (arguments.size() != 2) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "The 'caseInSensitiveMatching' function requires exactly two arguments.");
                }

                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

                buffer.append("(").append(arguments.get(0)).append(" ilike ").append(arguments.get(1)).append(")");

                return buffer.toString();
            }

        }

    }
```

The above optimization produced in our situation a performance improvement of a factor of 40 compared to the version with the `lower` function as Postgres could leverage the index on the corresponding column. In our situation the query execution time could be reduced from 4.5 seconds to 100 ms.

The `lower` prevents an efficient usage of the index and as such it is much slower.

Comment: This is so correct, the default implementation of JPA to implement case-insensitive comparison as `lower(left) like lower(right)` is _so_ bad, especially if you deal with large tables. Unfortunately I only have 1 upvote to give.

Comment: Sounds like `like lower` can be faster than `ilike`: https://www.visuality.pl/posts/ilike-vs-like-lower-postgres-stories

Answer (score 8):

This work for me  :

```
CriteriaBuilder critBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<CtfLibrary> critQ = critBuilder.createQuery(Users.class);
Root<CtfLibrary> root = critQ.from(Users.class);

Expression<String> path = root.get("lastName");
Expression<String> upper =critBuilder.upper(path);
Predicate ctfPredicate = critBuilder.like(upper,"%stringToFind%");
critQ.where(critBuilder.and(ctfPredicate));
em.createQuery(critQ.select(root)).getResultList();
```

Comment: Where in your code do you make sure that `stringToFind` is uppercase?

Answer (score 4):

Easier and more efficient to enforce case insensitity within the database than JPA.

1. Under the SQL 2003, 2006, 2008 standards, can do this by adding `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` OR `COLLATE latin1_general_cs` to the following:

   - Column Definition

     ```
     CREATE TABLE <table name> (
       <column name> <type name> [DEFAULT...] 
                                 [NOT NULL|UNIQUE|PRIMARY KEY|REFERENCES...]
                                 [COLLATE <collation name>], 
       ...
     )
     ```
   - Domain Definition

     ```
     CREATE DOMAIN <domain name> [ AS ] <data type>
       [ DEFAULT ... ] [ CHECK ... ] [ COLLATE <collation name> ]
     ```
   - Character Set Definition

     ```
     CREATE CHARACTER SET <character set name>
     [ AS ] GET <character set name> [ COLLATE <collation name> ]
     ```

   For full description of above refer: 
   http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#column%20definition
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-table.html
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx
2. In Oracle, can set NLS Session/Configuration parameters

   ```
    SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
    SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
    SQL> SELECT ename FROM emp1 WHERE ename LIKE 'McC%e';

    ENAME
    ----------------------
    McCoye
    Mccathye
   ```

   Or, in `init.ora` (or OS-specific name for initialization parameter file):

   ```
   NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC
   NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI
   ```

   Binary sorts can be case-insensitive or accent-insensitive. When you specify BINARY_CI as a value for NLS_SORT, it designates a sort that is accent-sensitive and case-insensitive. BINARY_AI designates an accent-insensitive and case-insensitive binary sort. You may want to use a binary sort if the binary sort order of the character set is appropriate for the character set you are using.
   Use the NLS_SORT session parameter to specify a case-insensitive or accent-insensitive sort:

   ```
   Append _CI to a sort name for a case-insensitive sort.
   Append _AI to a sort name for an accent-insensitive and case-insensitive sort.
   ```

   For example, you can set NLS_SORT to the following types of values:

   ```
   FRENCH_M_AI
   XGERMAN_CI
   ```

   Setting NLS_SORT to anything other than BINARY [with optional _CI or _AI] causes a sort to use a full table scan, regardless of the path chosen by the optimizer. BINARY is the exception because indexes are built according to a binary order of keys. Thus the optimizer can use an index to satisfy the ORDER BY clause when NLS_SORT is set to BINARY. If NLS_SORT is set to any linguistic sort, the optimizer must include a full table scan and a full sort in the execution plan.

   Or, if NLS_COMP is set to LINGUISTIC, as above, then sort settings can be applied locally to indexed columns, rather than globally across the database:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX emp_ci_index ON emp (NLSSORT(emp_name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'));
   ```

   Reference: [ORA 11g Linguistic Sorting and String Searching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm)
              [ORA 11g Setting Up a Globalization Support Environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG230)

Comment: Your link again points to this very question. I think recursion is not what you wanted ;)

Answer (score 2):

Desperated workaround for OpenJPA 2.3.0 and Postgresql

```
public class OpenJPAPostgresqlDictionaryPatch extends PostgresDictionary {

  @Override
  public SQLBuffer toOperation(String op, SQLBuffer selects, SQLBuffer from, SQLBuffer where, SQLBuffer group, SQLBuffer having, SQLBuffer order, boolean distinct, long start, long end, String forUpdateClause, boolean subselect) {
    String whereSQL = where.getSQL();
    int p = whereSQL.indexOf("LIKE");
    int offset = 0;
    while (p != -1) {
      where.replaceSqlString(p + offset, p + offset + 4, "ILIKE");
      p = whereSQL.indexOf("LIKE", p + 1);
      offset++;
    }
    return super.toOperation(op, selects, from, where, group, having, order, distinct, start, end, forUpdateClause, subselect);
  }

}
```

This is a fragile and ugly workaround for doing case insensitive LIKE operation with OpenJPA and Postgresql database. It replaces the LIKE operator to ILIKE operator in the generated SQL.

It is too bad that OpenJPA DBDictionary does not allow to change operator names.

Answer (score 2):

to use the [approach of Thomas Hunziker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62402298) with the criteria builder of hibernate you can provide a specific predicate implementation like the following

```java
public class ILikePredicate extends AbstractSimplePredicate implements Serializable {

    private final Expression<String> matchExpression;

    private final Expression<String> pattern;

    public ILikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        Expression<String> pattern) {
        super(criteriaBuilder);
        this.matchExpression = matchExpression;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public ILikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        String pattern) {
        this(criteriaBuilder, matchExpression, new LiteralExpression<>(criteriaBuilder, pattern));
    }

    public Expression<String> getMatchExpression() {
        return matchExpression;
    }

    public Expression<String> getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerParameters(ParameterRegistry registry) {
        Helper.possibleParameter(getMatchExpression(), registry);
        Helper.possibleParameter(getPattern(), registry);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(boolean isNegated, RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        String match = ((Renderable) getMatchExpression()).render(renderingContext);
        String pattern = ((Renderable) getPattern()).render(renderingContext);
        return String.format("function('caseInSensitiveMatching', %s, %s) = %s", match, pattern, !isNegated);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [weltraumpirat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547122/weltraumpirat) answer, in short for each desired field on your **Root** add the following **Predicate** to your predicate list

```
criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(<desired field on your root>)), "%" + text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) + "%")
```

Then obtain **TypedQuery** with desired OR-AND as follow

```
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[]{}))));
```

Answer (score -2):

Please consider to use

```
CriteriaBuilder.like(Expression<String> x, Expression<String> pattern, char escapeChar);
```

for matching anywhere.

Comment: Maybe add an example to elaborate?