# jpa criteriabuilder upper gives compilation error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm tying to use CriteriaBuilder for a case insensitive query as described here [hibernate jpa criteriabuilder ignore case queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635777/hibernate-jpa-criteriabuilder-ignore-case-queries) and in many other questions and tutorials around the web.

My code is:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    return builder.equal(builder.upper(root.get("firstName")), "test".toUpperCase());
}
```

but I'm getting a compile time error:

> The method upper(Expression<String>) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>)

The version of hibernate jpa I'm using is:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final</version>
```

Does it depend on the hibernate version I'm using? How to put an Expression<String> there instead of a Path<Object>?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As compiler said we it is expecting Expression in this case Path extends from Expression but you have a Path to fix this issue due the following.

```
return builder.equal(builder.upper(root.<String> get("firstName")), "test".toUpperCase());
```

Trick is add `<String>` before get method, hope that helps.

Comment: thank you! that was the problem, I was wondering about Expression vs Path and I was missing the point that it was expecting a String instead of an Object

Comment: This helped me as well. Thank you. 
Btw here is my little snippet incase this can help someone else.

criteriaQuery.select(cb.greatest(from.<Date>get(EVENT_TIME_STAMP)));