# Like ignore case in Spring data JDBC with Criteria

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Created a repository via Criteria.
I need the ability to search for a list of values ​​using the LIKE and IGNORE_CASE strings, just like in the POSTGRE `ILIKE` method.
I am limited is that I need pagable output of information.
I know that Spring Data JPA has such functionality, but another limitation is Spring Data JDBC.

When I started setting up Criteria, I discovered that .ignoreCase(true) did not work correctly, example:
list of values ​​in the database:

```
qwe
qwer
qwert
qwerty
Qwerty
QwertY
QWERTY
```

request `qwer`
response only one `QWERTY`

> spring-data-relational-3.1.0.jar

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Repository {

    private final JdbcAggregateTemplate jdbc;

    public Page<Account> getList(@NonNull AccountRequest filter, @NonNull Pageable pageable) {
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.empty();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filter.getAccountCode())) {
            criteria = criteria.and(ACCOUNT_CODE).like("%" + (filter.getAccountCode() + "%")).ignoreCase(true);
        }
        Query query = Query.query(criteria).with(pageable);

        List<Account> all = IteratorUtils.toList(jdbc.findAll(query, Account.class).iterator());
        long count = jdbc.count(Query.query(criteria), domainType);
        return new PageImpl<>(all, pageable, count);
    }
```

Expecting 6 occurrences but only getting 1

Is there a way to do manual ignoreCase taking into account paged output, or perhaps the problem was fixed in an update?

UPD:
I found a problem related to the generation of sql messages, the second UPPER method for a table field is missing

```
SELECT "account_dictionary"."id"           AS "id",
       "account_dictionary"."account_code" AS "account_code"
FROM "account_dictionary"
WHERE "account_dictionary".account_code LIKE UPPER(:account_code)
ORDER BY "account_dictionary".create_date DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Why doesn't it automatically create a second UPPER like that?

```
WHERE UPPER("account_dictionary".account_code) LIKE UPPER(:account_code)
```

Comment: If forcing the DB column to upper case is not an option, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635835/6650475) might help.  (But might not be performant or might not work for all characters.)

Comment: @Andrew S, I don't have the option to use CriteriaBuilder because it's strictly JDBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**: In the criteria you need to specify the column name in camelCase!

Answer (score 0):

[I tried to reproduce the issue](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow/blob/main/jdbc/case-insensitive-like/src/test/java/de/schauderhaft/caseinsensitivelike/CaseInsensitiveLikeApplicationTests.java) but failed to demonstrate the behaviour you describe, but I did find a problem.

`like` with ignore case seems to work just fine.
But a `Pageable` in the `Query` seems to get ignored.
But if you use `findAll(Query, Class, Pageable)` it works fine and you even get a complete `Page` instance back.
No need to manually execute the count and constructing the result.

#### My Reproducer

```java
record Demo (@Id Long id, String name){
    static Demo demo(String name) {
        return new Demo(null, name);
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
class CaseInsensitiveLikeApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    JdbcAggregateTemplate jdbc;


    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        jdbc.deleteAll(Demo.class);
        jdbc.saveAll(List.of(demo("ONE"), demo("drone"), demo("donE"), demo("other")));
    }


    @Test
    void likeWithIgnoreCaseWorksAsExpected() {

        assertThat(getList()).extracting(d -> d.name()).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("ONE", "drone", "donE");
    }

    @Test
    void pageableInQuery() {

        assertThat(getPage1(Pageable.ofSize(2))).hasSize(3); // this is actually not expected!
    }

    @Test
    void separatePageable() {

        assertThat(getPage2(Pageable.ofSize(2))).hasSize(2);
    }

    Iterable<Demo> getList() {

        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("name").like("%" + "One" + "%").ignoreCase(true);
        Query query = Query.query(criteria);

        return jdbc.findAll(query, Demo.class);
    }

    Iterable<Demo> getPage1(Pageable pageable) {

        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("name").like("%" + "ne" + "%").ignoreCase(true);
        Query query = Query.query(criteria);

        query.with(pageable);

        return jdbc.findAll(query, Demo.class);
    }

    Iterable<Demo> getPage2(Pageable pageable) {

        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("name").like("%" + "ne" + "%").ignoreCase(true);
        Query query = Query.query(criteria);

        return jdbc.findAll(query, Demo.class, pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of spring-data-relational do you have? @jens-schauder

Comment: thanks for the other pageable option!

Comment: Spring Data JDBC 3.1.4

Comment: I updated the spring-boot version to 3.1.4, but the situation did not change(
I'll try to build a new project and test the behavior on it

Comment: I found a problem related to the generation of sql messages, the second UPPER method for a table field is missing ```SELECT "account_dictionary"."id"           AS "id",
       "account_dictionary"."account_code" AS "account_code"
FROM "account_dictionary"
WHERE "account_dictionary".account_code LIKE UPPER(:account_code)
ORDER BY "account_dictionary".create_date DESC
LIMIT 50```

Comment: Could you please create a ticket for that at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues

Comment: I found the error by debugging! It turns out that you need to specify the column name in camelCase!