# ignorecase in criteria builder in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, jpa-2.0

How can we do a ignorecase in the criteria builder? If I have

```
private final CriteriaBuilder cb
```

then I can only use `cb.asc` or `cb.desc`, but not ignoring case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA2: Case-insensitive like matching anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580285/jpa2-case-insensitive-like-matching-anywhere)

Comment: did not help the link

Comment: It should. As you have pointed out, there is no option to enable ignorecase on a CriteriaBuilder. Therefore, just convert both the search term and the result to either upper or lower case, and you'll achieve the same thing.

Comment: i have used the criteriaQuery query and used the orderBy expression

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> *How can we do a ignorecase in the criteria builder*

**1. Force Ignorecase in JPA Program - Does the Job, Answers the Q Directly**

- For a one-arg operation (i.e. ORDER BY), convert argument to lowercase (or uppercase).
- For a two-arg operation (e.g. = or LIKE or ORDER BY), convert both args to LC (or UC).

JPA ORDER BY Two Columns, Ignoring Case:

```
 Order lcSurnameOrder = criteriaBuilder.order(
     criteriaBuilder.lower(Person_.surname));
 Order lcFirstnameOrder = criteriaBuilder.order(
     criteriaBuilder.lower(Person_.firstname));    
 criteriaQuery.orderBy(lcSurnameOrder, lcFirstnameOrder);
```

JPA LIKE, Ignoring Case:

```
 Predicate lcSurnameLikeSearchPattern = criteriaBuilder.like(
     criteriaBuilder.lower(Person_.surname), 
     searchPattern.toLowerCase());
 criteriaQuery.where(lcSurnameLikeSearchPattern);
```

Assumes Person_ canonical metamodel class was generated from Person entity, to give strong-typed use of JPA criteria API.

TIP: For best performance & control, consider converting string columns to LOWER case or INITCAP case just once - when you INSERT/UPDATE into the database.  Do the same conversion for user-entered search patterns.

**2. ALTERNATIVE: Apply Collation in the Database - Best Practice, Simpler, More Performant**

- The SQL-99 standard has a built-in modifer to compare characters in Strings according to rules:

  ```
  COLLATE <collation name>
  ```

  Can use when comparing, sorting and grouping on strings.  A common example that ignores case:

  ```
  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  ```

  Or

  ```
  COLLATE latin1_general_cs
  ```

  You can even create your own custom collation:

  ```
  CREATE COLLATION <collation name> FOR <character set specification>
    FROM <existing collation name> [ <pad characteristic> ]
  ```
- Collation is applied in the DB via one of the following alternatives (from localised to global effect):

  - **WHERE Clause (=, LIKE, HAVING, >, >=, etc)**

    ```
    WHERE <expression> = <expression> [COLLATE <collation name>]

    WHERE <expression> LIKE <expression> [COLLATE <collation name>]
    ```
  - **SELECT DISTINCT Clause**

    ```
    SELECT DISTINCT <expression> [COLLATE <collation name>], ...
    ```
  - **ORDER BY Clause**

    ```
    ORDER BY <expression> [COLLATE <collation name>]
    ```
  - **GROUP BY Clause**

    ```
    GROUP BY <expression> [COLLATE <collation name>]
    ```
  - **Column Definition**

    ```
    CREATE TABLE <table name> (
      <column name> <type name> [DEFAULT...] 
                                [NOT NULL|UNIQUE|PRIMARY KEY|REFERENCES...]
                                [COLLATE <collation name>], 
      ...
    )
    ```
  - **Domain Definition**

    ```
    CREATE DOMAIN <domain name> [ AS ] <data type>
      [ DEFAULT ... ] [ CHECK ... ] [ COLLATE <collation name> ]
    ```
  - **Character Set Definition**

    ```
    CREATE CHARACTER SET <character set name>
    [ AS ] GET <character set name> [ COLLATE <collation name> ]
    ```
- **The first 4 cases can't be used with JPA, because these SQL commands are generated by JPA, and JPA standard does not support collation.**
- **The last 3 cases can be used with JPA.**
- ***So: create TABLES with COLUMNS that have collation "turned on" and subsequently ORDER BY, =, LIKE, etc will ignore case automatically.  Then no work is required in JPA - no need for any conversion or requesting to ignore case.***

**3. ALTERNATIVE (PROPRIETARY) Oracle also provides NLS settings to ignore case across entire DB instance (can be set in config files):**

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='BINARY';    -- Case Sensitive
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='ANSI';      -- Ignore for LIKE but not =,<,etc
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='LINGUISTIC';-- Ignore for LIKE,=,<,etc (post 10gR2)

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='BINARY' ;   -- Case Sensitive
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='BINARY_CI'; -- Ignore
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='XSPANISH';  -- Ignore according to language rules
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='LATIN1_GENERAL_CS';
```

Plus functions to ignore case as one-off

```
ORDER BY NLSSORT(supplier_name,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI') ;
```

You can call this via

```
criteriaBuilder.function("nlssort", String.class, dept_.suppler_name, "NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI");
```

and then call `criteriaQuery.orderyBy` or `select`, etc

Comment: How is `Person_.surname` defined?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík it's called MetaModel,  check https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries-metamodel