# Criteriabuilder lower() vs Java toLowerCase()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

According to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611904/ignorecase-in-criteria-builder-in-jpa)

> Predicate lcSurnameLikeSearchPattern = criteriaBuilder.like(
>        criteriaBuilder.**lower**(Person_.surname), 
>        searchPattern.**toLowerCase**());

This seems like Hibernate would generate an SQL that would look something like

```
LOWER(PERSON.SURNAME) LIKE 'searchPattern'
```

Where searchPattern would have been lowered in Java using whatever implementation toLowerCase would provide. Whereas the query LOWER would use Oracle implementation. For ASCII characters, I'm guessing things are pretty simple, but would there ever be discrepancies on international UTF characters?

How would I get JPA to lower both operands of LIKE in the query? So the generated query looks like

```
LOWER(PERSON.SURNAME) LIKE LOWER('searchPattern')
```

Comment: Why not try it by yourself? :)

Comment: What does that even mean? Did you read my entire post or did you just read the title and decided to post a comment?

Comment: Marco means that a lot of questions can be answered by trying (and reading the documentation and javadoc), if `criteriaBuilder.lower(Person_.surname)` generates `LOWER(PERSON.SURNAME)`, then you can assume (and validate by trying) that `criteriaBuilder.lower(searchPattern)` might generate `LOWER('searchPattern')`. Given the [answer by Vlastimil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35081558/466862) this is not correct, but it might have given you an insight in what to do.

Comment: Thanks. I did ultimately find the answer. When I posted this, I had searched and read for days. This is not a trivial concept by any means, and any search for the topic mostly returns the same toLowerCase solution. I would not have asked here, if I could have discovered the answer myself. The fact that I asked here means I was desperately seeking an answer. Then to be told to try it myself without any hints or pointers seems like a smug, useless and unproductive comment. I understand that no one owes me anything, but if someone cannot help without being smug, they're best to remain silent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use two Expressions as `like` method parameters and `literal` to wrap a String into Expression:

```
Predicate lcSurnameLikeSearchPattern = criteriaBuilder.like(
  criteriaBuilder.lower(Person_.surname),
  criteriaBuilder.lower(criteriaBuilder.literal(searchPattern))
);
```

[CriteriaBuilder#like(Expression,Expression)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression))

[CriteriaBuilder#lower(Expression)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lower(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression))

[CriteriaBuilder#literal(T)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#literal(T))

*I ommit `Person_.surname` definition as it is from your example.*