# How search case insensitive values using Criteria, MongoTemplate and Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, criteria, case-insensitive

I'm currently doing:

```
criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(where("car.color").is(car_color),
                                      where("car_size").is(car_size))
```

How to make this search works for both `car_color = BLUE` and `car_color = blue` ?

---

Update:

This partially works:

```
where("car.color").regex(car_color, "i"),
```

But then all values below would be updated:

```
BLUE
BBLUE
blue
bluee
```

And I want to update only what is matched in the `car_color` variable(case insensitive).

Comment: Don`t know your API, but dont you have a select uppercase to compare with equals uppercase criteria? like ```SELECT * FROM cars where UPPER('car.color') = 'BLUE'```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have some entries in the database with upper/lower case that can't be updated, so that won't work.

Comment: The idea of the select upper is to change the result of the query not to update the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem is:

```
criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(where("car.color").regex("^" + car_color+ "$", "i"),
                                      where("car_size").is(car_size))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to pre process your string to be all caps or all lowercase. In java that's done like:

`car_color.toLowerCase()`
or
`car_color.toUpperCase()`

Then you know its all in caps or all in lowercase, and can compare the string appropriately

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, but thanks for the suggestion. I already have some entries in the database with upper/lower case that can't be updated.

Comment: ah I see, sorry I couldn't have been of more help. Im not super familiar with the Criteria API, but maybe this previous post will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580285/jpa2-case-insensitive-like-matching-anywhere